# Computing how many folders each folder has in a complex folder structure?

Tags: r, tree, hierarchical-data, directory

Consider the following `tree`:

```
library(data.tree)

acme <- Node$new("Acme Inc.")
    accounting <- acme$AddChild("Accounting")
        software <- accounting$AddChild("New Software")
        standards <- accounting$AddChild("New Accounting Standards")
    research <- acme$AddChild("Research")
        newProductLine <- research$AddChild("New Product Line")
        newLabs <- research$AddChild("New Labs")
    it <- acme$AddChild("IT")
        outsource <- it$AddChild("Outsource")
        agile <- it$AddChild("Go agile")
        goToR <- it$AddChild("Switch to R")
```

I then want to compute the `averageBranchingFactor`:

```
averageBranchingFactor(acme)
```

This yields`2.5`

However, for various reasons I want to be able to get all the branching factors, not only the average branching factor. I need this to, for example, compare two file structures statistically with regards to significant differences across average branching factors.

According to the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/data.tree.pdf) for `data.tree` the `AverageBranchingFactor()` function performs the following: "calculate the average number of branches each non-leaf has." Therefore, I first tried the following:

```
acme.df <- ToDataFrameTree(acme, "averageBranchingFactor")
mean(acme.df$averageBranchingFactor[acme.df$averageBranchingFactor>0])
```

This yields `2.375`, which then lead me to try a simpler version:

```
mean(acme.df$averageBranchingFactor)
```

This yields `0.8636364`

How do I arrive at all the individual branching factors that together have a mean of `2.5`?

Ideally I would like to create a `data.frame` that lists every folder, with a variable where the branching factor is listed for every folder. For example, I have this very simply folder structure:

```
top_level_folder
    sub_folder_1
    sub_folder_2
         sub_folder_3
```

Answering the question would involve creating an output that looks like this:

```
Folders             Subfolders (BranchingFactor)
top_level_folder    2
sub_folder_1        0
sub_folder_2        1
sub_folder_3        0
```

The first column can simply be generated through calling `list.dirs("/Users/username/Downloads/top_level/")`, but I don't know how to generate the second column. Note that the second column is non-recursive, meaning that folders within subfolders are not counted (i.e. `top_level_folder` contains only 2 subfolders, even though `sub_folder_2` contains another folder, `sub_folder_2` ).

If you want to see whether your solution scales or not, download the Rails codebase: https://github.com/rails/rails/archive/master.zip and try it on Rails' more complex file structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply loop along the folder structure and count the nunber of folders (without recursivity) at each level :

```
dir.create("top_level_folder/sub_folder_2/sub_folder_3", recursive = TRUE)
dir.create("top_level_folder/sub_folder_1")


dirs <- list.dirs()
branching_factor <- vector(length = length(dirs))
for (i in 1:length(dirs)) {
    branching_factor[i] <- length(list.dirs(path = dirs[i], 
                                            full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE))
}

result <- data.frame(Folders = basename(dirs), BranchingFactor = branching_factor)
result[-1,]
```

You could also use a shorter, more idomatic and vectorised version of this code :

```
dirs <- list.dirs()
branching_factor <- sapply(dirs, function(x) length(list.dirs(x, FALSE, FALSE)))
result2 <- data.frame(Folders = basename(dirs), BranchingFactor = branching_factor, 
                      row.names = NULL)[-1,]
```

The results looks like that :

```
> head(result2[rev(order(result2[,2])),])
          Folders BranchingFactor
208      fixtures              24
122      fixtures              23
42       fixtures              18
440      core_ext              17
340 active_record              17
562         rails              16
```

Comment: apply your code on [https://github.com/rails/rails/archive/master.zip](https://github.com/rails/rails/archive/master.zip), the `result` is not correct

Comment: The reason being :  `length(dir(path = dirs[i]))` is also counting`.yml` and `.md` files

Comment: You are right thank you ! See the edited version. It seems that the former code (using `dir`  instead of `list.dirs` within the loop was counting all files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

Just correcting @Gilles solution,

```
path <- "SO/rails-master/"
dirs <- list.dirs(path)
branching_factor <- vector(length = length(dirs))
for (i in 1:length(dirs)) {
   branching_factor[i] <- length(list.dirs(path = dirs[i], recursive = FALSE))
}

result <- data.frame(Folders = basename(dirs), BranchingFactor = branching_factor)

> head(result)
       Folders BranchingFactor
1 rails-master              14
2      .github               0
3  actioncable               4
4          app               1
5       assets               1
6  javascripts               1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @histelheim, he has updated his solution correctly now

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a list of all folders recursively, then making a table of folder subfolder pairs, from these I can count the number of subfolder by folder.

I miss empty folders though, so I remerge this with the initial folders with a left join, and I fill in the NAs with zeroes.

```
path <- getwd()
all_folders <- path %>% list.dirs(full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE) %>% 

data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>% setNames("Folders")
all_sub_folders <- all_folders$Folders %>%
  strsplit("/") %>%
  lapply(function(x){c(x[length(x)-1],x[length(x)])}) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
  setNames(c("ParentFolders","Folders"))
output <- all_sub_folders$ParentFolders %>% table %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>% setNames(c("Folders","SubFolders")))
output <- merge(all_sub_folders,output,all.x = TRUE)[,c("Folders","SubFolders")]
output$SubFolders[is.na(output$SubFolders)] <- 0
output <- output[match(all_sub_folders$Folders,output$Folders),]

head(output)
#      Folders SubFolders
# 2160   Rhome        126
# 17   acepack          5
# 856     help          1
# 992     html          9
# 1486    libs        124
# 1130    i386          0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44610537/4497050) on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44514392/4497050), substituting `list.dirs` with `recursive = FALSE` for `list.files`:

```r
library(purrr)

files <- .libPaths()[1] %>%    # omit for current directory or supply alternate path
    list.dirs() %>% 
    map_df(~list(path = .x, 
                 dirs = length(list.dirs(.x, recursive = FALSE))))

files
#> # A tibble: 4,457 x 2
#>                                                                           path  dirs
#>                                                                          <chr> <int>
#>  1              /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library   314
#>  2        /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind     4
#>  3   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/help     0
#>  4   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/html     0
#>  5   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/Meta     0
#>  6      /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/R     0
#>  7      /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/acepack     5
#>  8 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/acepack/help     0
#>  9 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/acepack/html     0
#> 10 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/acepack/libs     1
#> # ... with 4,447 more rows

mean(files$dirs[files$dirs != 0])
#> [1] 2.952949
```

or in base R,

```r
files <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.dirs(.libPaths()[1]), function(path){
    data.frame(path = path, 
               dirs = length(list.dirs(path, recursive = FALSE)), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}))

head(files)
#>                                                                        path dirs
#> 1            /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library  314
#> 2      /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind    4
#> 3 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/help    0
#> 4 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/html    0
#> 5 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/Meta    0
#> 6    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/R    0

mean(files$dirs[files$dirs != 0])
#> [1] 2.952949
```

Answer (score 0):

The averageBranchingFactor excludes leaves.
Side note: you can get acme directly using `data(acme)`.

```
library(data.tree)
data(acme)
acme$averageBranchingFactor
acme$count
print(acme, abf = "averageBranchingFactor", "count")
```

This will show like that:

```
                          levelName abf count
1  Acme Inc.                        2.5     3
2   ¦--Accounting                   2.0     2
3   ¦   ¦--New Software             0.0     0
4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards 0.0     0
5   ¦--Research                     2.0     2
6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line         0.0     0
7   ¦   °--New Labs                 0.0     0
8   °--IT                           3.0     3
9       ¦--Outsource                0.0     0
10      ¦--Go agile                 0.0     0
11      °--Switch to R              0.0     0
```

The implementation of `?averageBranchingFactor` does not bear any secrets, so you can tweak it to your needs. Simply type `averageBranchingFactor` into your console (without parenthesis):

```
function (node) 
{
    t <- Traverse(node, filterFun = isNotLeaf)
    if (length(t) == 0) 
        return(0)
    cnt <- Get(t, "count")
    if (!is.numeric(cnt)) 
        browser()
    return(mean(cnt))
}
```

In short, we traverse the tree (except leaves), and get the `count` value for each node. Finally, we calculate the mean.

Hope that helps.