# Compute number of files per folder in a complex folder structure?

Tags: r, path, tree, hierarchical-data, directory

I have created a simple `data.tree` through importing a folder structure with files inside of it.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load_gh("trinker/pathr")

library(pathr)
library(data.tree)

folder_structure <- pathr::tree(path = "/Users/username/Downloads/top_level/",
 use.data.tree = T, include.files = T)
```

Now, I would like to convert the object `folder_structure` into a `data.frame` with one row per folder and a column that specifies how many files each folder contains. How can I accomplish this?

For example, I have this very simply folder structure:

```
top_level_folder
    sub_folder_1
        file1.txt
    sub_folder_2
        file2.txt
```

Answering the question would involve creating an output that looks like this:

```
Folders             Files
top_level_folder    0
sub_folder_1        1
sub_folder_2        1
```

The first column can simply be generated through calling `list.dirs("/Users/username/Downloads/top_level/")`, but I don't know how to generate the second column. Note that the second column is non-recursive, meaning that files within subfolders are not counted (i.e. `top_level_folder` contains `0` files, even though the subfolders of `top_level_folder` contains 2 files).

If you want to see whether your solution scales or not, download the Rails codebase: https://github.com/rails/rails/archive/master.zip and try it on Rails' more complex file structure.

Comment: Where can I get the `pathr` package?

Comment: @Jimbou: https://github.com/trinker/pathr

Comment: Can you clarify whether `sub_folder_1` refers to the same folder? I.e. is it one folder with two files, or is it two folders---with the same name, which wouldn't work---and thus should be `sub_folder_1` and `sub_folder_2`?

Comment: @Felix - that was a mistake, it should be `sub_folder_2`--sorry about that! I've corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.dirs()` provides a vector of every subdirectory reachable from a starting folder, so that handles the first column of your data-frame. Very convenient.

```
# Get a vector of all the directories and subdirectories from this folder
dir <- "."
xs <- list.dirs(dir, recursive = TRUE)
```

`list.files()` can tell us the contents of each of those folders, but it includes files and folders. We just want the files. To get the count of files, we need to filter the output of `list.files()` with a predicate. `file.info()` can tell us whether a given file is a directory or not, so we build our predicate from that.

```
# Helper to check if something is folder or file
is_dir <- function(x) file.info(x)[["isdir"]]
is_file <- Negate(is_dir)
```

Now, we solve how to get the number of files in a single folder. Summing boolean values returns the number of `TRUE` cases.

```
# Count the files in a single folder
count_files_in_one_dir <- function(dir) {
  files <- list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)
  sum(is_file(files))
}
```

For convenience, we wrap that function to make it work on many folders.

```
# Vectorized version of the above
count_files_in_dir <- function(dir) {
  vapply(dir, count_files_in_one_dir, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
```

Now we can count the files.

```
df <- tibble::data_frame(
  dir = xs,
  nfiles = count_files_in_dir(xs))

df
#> # A tibble: 688 x 2
#>                                                  dir nfiles
#>                                                <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1                                                 .     11
#>  2                                         ./.github      3
#>  3                                     ./actioncable      7
#>  4                                 ./actioncable/app      0
#>  5                          ./actioncable/app/assets      0
#>  6              ./actioncable/app/assets/javascripts      1
#>  7 ./actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable      5
#>  8                                 ./actioncable/bin      1
#>  9                                 ./actioncable/lib      1
#> 10                    ./actioncable/lib/action_cable      8
#> # ... with 678 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dplyr` chain with the `parse_path()` function from the `pathr` package. The `tree` function is basically just a wrapper around `parse_path` so it's easier to use `parse_path` directly. E.g. like this:

```
library(pathr)
library(dplyr)

fls <- dir("C:/RBuildTools/3.3", recursive = T, full.names = T) %>% 
parse_path() %>% 
index(4) %>% # this is where you indicate the level or "depth" 
             # of the folder of which want subfolder file counts
data.frame(folders = .) %>% 
group_by(folders) %>% 
tally() %>% 
arrange(n)

# if you want to get rid of all the files in your starting folder 
# just add a 
# filter(folder > 1) at the end of the dplyr chain
```

For me the above code produces the following result:

```
> fls
# A tibble: 12 × 2
        folders     n
         <fctr> <int>
1       COPYING     1
2    README.txt     1
3    Rtools.txt     1
4  unins000.dat     1
5  unins000.exe     1
6   VERSION.txt     1
7           bin    56
8    mingw_libs   200
9      texinfo5   356
10    gcc-4.6.3  3787
11     mingw_32 13707
12     mingw_64 14619
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working at all for me. I've updated the answer to show more specifically how the output needs to look. With your script I do not get any of the information necessary for the example folder structure. Also I am not sure what you mean by "depth"--where do you start counting the depth, and in which direction does it go?

Comment: For example, if I call your function on `"/Users/username/Downloads/top_level/"` then I simply get `Folder=Downloads` and `N=2`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, my answer was unclear. Theoretically, given your last example you should change `index(4)` to `index(5)`, since you want to count all folders after the fifth slash or folder (that's what I meant with depth. I realize this was not clear, I'm going to reformulate it)

Comment: But I also realize that you asked for non-recursive folder count (i.e. not counting all the files in potential subfolders). That is a bit more tricky to do, since the `R`'s `dir()` only has `recursive = T/F` option, not how deep the command should climb in the subfolders--which would be necessary for an exact count. I'll see whether I can come up with a solution for that problem, but let's first see if we can get the code above running on your machine

Comment: yes, if I set the folder depth to 5 and 6 respectively, I can get the file count for each of the 3 folders in the example. However, it is recursive. Also, how would I use this for a large and complex folder structure if I don't know all the folder depths?

Answer (score 1):

```
dir.create("top_level_folder")
dir.create("top_level_folder/sub_folder_1")
dir.create("top_level_folder/sub_folder_2")
a <- "hello"
save(a,file = "top_level_folder/sub_folder_1/file1.txt")
save(a,file = "top_level_folder/sub_folder_2/file2.txt")

path <- "top_level_folder"
files   <- list.files(path, recursive=TRUE)
folders <- sapply(strsplit(files,"/"),function(x){x[length(x)-1]})
output <- setNames(as.data.frame(table(unlist(folders))),c("Folders","Files"))

all_folders <- data.frame(Folders = list.dirs(path,full.names=FALSE,recursive=TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
all_folders$Folders[1] <- strsplit(path,",")[[1]][length(strsplit(path,",")[[1]])]

output <- merge(all_folders,output,all.x = TRUE)
output$Files[is.na(output$Files)] <- 0
output <- output[match(all_folders$Folders,output$Folders),]

#            Folders Files
# 3 top_level_folder     0
# 1     sub_folder_1     1
# 2     sub_folder_2     1
```

Comment: It works for that limited example, but as soon as I scale up to a more complex file structure it fails: `Error in table(folders) : all arguments must have the same length`

Comment: You can for example download the Rails code base and try it on that: https://github.com/rails/rails/archive/master.zip

Comment: I got the same error when trying it into my profram files full folder, but it works when I change folders into unlist(folders), can you try the new script ?

Comment: this seems to work. Is this recursive on non-recursive?

Comment: it's recursive, you can try `sample(files,100)` to see a sample of what's counted

Comment: Yes, I think it is recursive--the average number of files/folder is much higher than when I calculate the overall average using `pathr`. The solution, however, needs to be non-recursive. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: if you mean that files in subfolders shouldn't considered for the parent folder count, it works already this way... I'll try to reproduce your example so we can start from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146778/discussion-between-histelheim-and-moody-mudskipper).

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is make a list of directories with `list.dirs` (which defaults to `recursive = TRUE`) and the iterate over it, finding the length of `list.files` (which defaults to `recursive = FALSE`) for that directory. Neatening to a nice data.frame,

```r
library(purrr)

files <- .libPaths()[1] %>%    # omit for current directory or supply alternate path
    list.dirs() %>% 
    map_df(~list(path = .x, 
                 files = length(list.files(.x))))

files
#> # A tibble: 4,457 x 2
#>                                                                           path files
#>                                                                          <chr> <int>
#>  1              /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library   314
#>  2        /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind     9
#>  3   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/help     5
#>  4   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/html     2
#>  5   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/Meta     6
#>  6      /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/R     3
#>  7      /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/acepack    14
#>  8 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/acepack/help     5
#>  9 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/acepack/html     2
#> 10 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/acepack/libs     2
#> # ... with 4,447 more rows
```

or all in base if you prefer,

```r
files <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.dirs(.libPaths()[1]), function(path){
    data.frame(path = path, 
               files = length(list.files(path)), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}))

head(files)
#>                                                                        path files
#> 1            /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library   314
#> 2      /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind     9
#> 3 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/help     5
#> 4 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/html     2
#> 5 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/Meta     6
#> 6    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/abind/R     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very compact solution:

```
print(folder_structure, 
      files = function(node) sum(Get(node$children, 'isLeaf')), 
      filterFun = isNotLeaf,
      pruneMethod = NULL
)
```

This produces something like this:

```
                                                     levelName files
1   data.tree                                                     16
2    ¦--data                                                       2
3    ¦--data_gen                                                   2
4    ¦--.git                                                       8
5    ¦   ¦--hooks                                                  9
6    ¦   ¦--info                                                   1
7    ¦   ¦--logs                                                   1
8    ¦   ¦   °--refs                                               1
9    ¦   ¦       ¦--heads                                          4
10   ¦   ¦       ¦--remotes                                        0
11   ¦   ¦       ¦   °--origin                                     5
12   ¦   ¦--objects                                                0
13   ¦   ¦   ¦--01                                                 4
14   ¦   ¦   ¦--02                                                 5
...
```

Note, however, that this counts empty folders as files too.

Answer (score 0):

`list.files` returns all file and directory paths. There is no `is.file` function, but there is `dir.exists`. Since we know all the paths are actual nodes, those that aren't directories will be counted as files.

```
top_level <- '~/rails-master'
setwd(top_level)
subitems <- data.frame(
  path = list.files(
    include.dirs = TRUE,
    recursive    = TRUE
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
subitems$is_file <- !dir.exists(subitems$path)
```

For each row, if the path is to a directory, then it's its own directory path.  If the path's for a file, then its parent is the directory path. Then it's simply a matter of counting how often `is_file` is true by directory path.

```
subitems$dir_path <- ifelse(
  subitems$is_file,
  dirname(subitems$path),
  subitems$path
)
file_counts <- tapply(subitems$is_file, subitems$dir_path, sum)
result <- data.frame(
  Folders = names(file_counts),
  Files   = file_counts
)
```